# Convert Databricks SQL Query to DAX

Tags: sql, dax, databricks-sql, daxstudio

I have the below databricks sql query and I need help to convert into DAX by using lookup.

```
select distinct P.ProgramId
,P.ProgramName
,DU.InternalEmailAddress
from gold.programid P
  INNER Join gold.dimclinic C ON P.ProgramId = C.ProgramId
  INNER Join gold.userclinicbridge UC ON C.ClinicId = UC.ClinicId
  INNER JOIN gold.dimuser DU ON DU.UserId = UC.UserId
WHERE DU.InternalEmailAddress = @UserId
```

Thanks,

Comment: too vague.  I typically write DAX against "tables" that are produced by some process in Power Query Editor, not directly against the database tables.  Please describe more of your process and the tools you are using.

Comment: Also, please describe what attempts you have already made to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi,
I have a paginated report which access the source as Power BI data model, both are deployed in service.  I have set of parameters exist in Paginated Report. For ex. ProgramName. It contains list of programnames and use will select the respective program for seeing the data. Now, we have RLS implemented in data model and it is working fine. However, the user can see all the programs in parameter rather he want see only his program. I am planning to restrict the program names in parameter based on user logged in to the system. I have tried to convert the above sql as below DAX.

Comment: EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS(
   'Program'[ProgramId],
   'Program'[ProgramName],
   LOOKUPVALUE('dimclinic'[ProgramId],'Program'[ProgramId]),
   LOOKUPVALUE('userclinicbridge'[ClinicId],'dimclinic'[ClinicId]),
"InternalEmailAddress",LOOKUPVALUE('dimuser'[InternalEmailAddress],'dimuser'[UserId],'userclinicbridge'[ClinicId])
   )
I need to apply filter as I mentioned in SQL. As I am new to DAX, seeking some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the DAX for a paginated report...

The [DaxStudio Getting Connected documentation](https://daxstudio.org/docs/tutorials/getting-connected/) includes this section:
Connecting to Power BI Premium XMLA Endpoint

You don't say that you are connecting to a premium workspace, but I'll assume you are.

Based on my first 2 minutes in DaxStudio:

1. Open DaxStudio
2. Connect to the workspace
3. Connect to the dataset
4. Drag and drop items from your dataset to the appropriate boxes in
   DaxStudio
5. Click Update to generate the DAX   Click Run to verify
   it's working as expected
6. Copy the DAX from DaxStudio to Power BI Report Builder

Problems you may encounter appear to be:

1. You are not using a premium workspace.
2. Row-level security will need to be done differently from what you are currently doing.
3. The data model in your data set doesn't join the tables correctly.